# what happens when we do not returns super.onOptionsItemSelected() in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)?

Tags: android

I don't understand what happens when I don't return super.onCreateItemSelected(item). Does android take it by default?

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemThatWasClickedId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemThatWasClickedId == R.id.action_search) {
            Context context = MainActivity.this;
            String textToShow = "Search clicked";
            Toast.makeText(context, textToShow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

This code ran fine. But everywhere I see use to super.onCreateItemSelected(item).

Comment: "But everywhere I see use to super.onCreateItemSelected(item)" -- hopefully, you do not see that anywhere, as there is no `onCreateItemSelected()` in the Android SDK. You will see `super.onOptionsItemSelected()` called from `onOptionsItemSelected()`, though, to give the superclass a chance to handle anything it may have added to the action bar.

Comment: by mistake I copied onCreateItemSelected(). Thanks by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The super class may need to handle occurrences in the action/tool bar.
So it is essential to call the super classes onOptionsItemSelected.